# Allow only specific values for key in Joi schema

Tags: javascript, joi

Is there any other way to set specific values in Joi validation schema for key except regex pattern?

My example schema:

```
const schema = joi.object().keys({
    query: joi.object().keys({
        // allow only apple and banana
        id: joi.string().regex(/^(apple|banana)$/).required(),
    }).required(),
})
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can also use `valid` like

```
const schema = joi.object().keys({
  query: joi.object().keys({
    // allow only apple and banana
    id: joi.string().valid('apple','banana').required(),
  }).required(),
})
```

Reference: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#anyvalidvalue---aliases-only-equal

Comment: it is allowing only one among two, How can we make it for both.

Comment: how can I prevent price key in payload 

              price: Joi.when('pricing', {
                is: 'FIXED',
                then: //prevent adding price here,
                otherwise: Joi.number()
                  .min(1)
                  .max(1000)
                  .required()
              })

Comment: @tareknoaman First off, that sounds pretty unrelated to this question. But you might be able to omit the 'then'. If that doesn't work, make a new question.

Comment: @VinodKumarMarupu Your comment makes no sense. A string can only be one value at time. You would probably use an array or an additional key to allow more values.

Answer (score 8):

You can try with .valid() to allow joi only with that specific string .

```
const schema = joi.object().keys({
  query: joi.object().keys({
    role: joi.string().valid('admin','student').required(), // joi would allow only if role is admin or student.
  }).required(),
})
```

This is absolutely equal to giving "enam" field in mongoose ODM for representing objects in mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept one or more values (apple, banana or both) you can use `allow`: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0#anyallowvalues